# how to make Flutter ValueListenableBuilder to update the ui every time the the app request data from the server

Tags: api, flutter, mobile

Im new to flutter and was wondering if there is any example codes explaining how to preform live updates to the ui each time the rest api get is called. i want the builder to listen to a predefine variable that will be changed every time the api data as been requested. I wanted to try stream builder but i dont want to spam request from the server. If any one have any advice or method to preforming this task please kindly explain, If you have any example codes on the exact thing please share . thank you

Comment: "I wanted to try stream builder but i dont want to spam request from the server", can you please elaborate on this? In order to understand what exactly it is you are trying to avoid and perhaps give very advise. What have you tried besides streambuilder? Can you please post a minimal code for the value listenable boiler plate you have setup so far?

Comment: I dont know if im correct or not. but i thought repeatedly calling for the api is not the exact out come im looking . i already have a api responding the data thats already in the db. i just want to to call it when ever the app launches and when ever the function is called. what i want is a way for the builder to listen to a certain variable changes to update the  UI.

Comment: If you want to call it once when the app opens or when the the user refreshes it deliberately, then you can use a future builder instead of a stream builder. If your API supports streaming, then you should setup a listener for this stream. This stream can be a centralized stream with UI listening to changes, or a streambuilder that combines both. But a stream builder doesn't keep calling the API, it's listening to the API, if no new data is sent by the API, no requests are made from the stream listener.